# MySQL get quantities from last 12 months grouped by month

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to write a MySQL SELECT statement in PHP.

I have 2 tables, `sales` and `sale_items`.

sales has columns: `sale_id`, `status`

sale_items has columns: `sale_id`, `date_added` (DATETIME), `quantity`

I need to return the quantities from `sale_items`, over the last 12 months grouped by month and where the `status` of the corresponding row in `sales` is equal to 'completed' (as you can see, `sales` and `sale_items` can be joined by `sale_id`).

I have tried modifying both of the following to suit my needs, but with no luck:

[MySQL monthly Sale of last 12 months including months with no Sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600863/mysql-monthly-sale-of-last-12-months-including-months-with-no-sale)

[Mysql sum for last 12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275659/mysql-sum-for-last-12-months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy you can use MySQL [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function for this along with **GROUP BY** caluse.

```
SELECT SUM(SI.quantity),MONTH(SI.date_added)
FROM sale_items SI
JOIN sales S
ON S.id=SI.sale_id
WHERE S.status = 'completed'
GROUP BY MONTH(SI.date_added);
```

Comment: Well this makes certain, grave assumptions about the dataset

Comment: I assume you're talking about date field, Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the `date_added` field is the one to be used to group, I will give this a try shortly

Comment: Works a treat, can't believe I thought this would be harder than it was

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(quantity),MONTH(SI.date_added)
FROM sale_items SI
JOIN sales S
ON S.id=SI.sale_id
WHERE S.status = 'completed'
GROUP BY MONTH(SI.date_added);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Ok I will explane more next time sorry.